# Ajax login script header problem

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers, prototypejs

I have a ajax login script, using prototype, where I ajax the credentials over to a php page that checks if the info is correct. If it is, I try to set a cookie and then return 0 or 1 depending if it is correct. The ajax call returns 0 if it is correct and then makes a js call on the original page to redirect into the site. I keep getting a cannot modify header information error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your "headers already sent" error should also tell you which output has caused the error with something like "output started at .. on line .." This should be point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your PHP isn't outputting any content before the line which sets the cookie. This includes whitespace - so make sure your code doesn't look like this:

```
<!-- some comment, new line, or something else before the php opening tag -->
<?php // This should be on line 1, with no space before it.
```

Comment: + make sure, that no includes have any whitespace outside of <?php ?> blocks, including after closing the last ?>. That's why many frameworks recommend omitting the closing ?> in files, as the PHP interpreter stops at the end of files. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236493/what-are-the-arguments-in-favor-of-php-closing-tags-for-php-only-files

Comment: also check that you do not print/echo anything before finishing setting the cookie. if you use output buffering then make sure you don't flush before finishing with the cookie.