# Facebook Share button - Scraper doesn't fetch meta tags

Tags: facebook, share, doctype, meta-tags, scraper

I've been working on this page
http://www.btselem.org/hebrew/131606

I decided to add the Facebook Share button, but for some reason whenever I try sharing, the Facebook scraper doesn't manage to get any of the meta tags in the source – it only displays the site's URL.
After checking the URL in the facebook developers debugging tool, I got a **206 response code** and the following error:

**Can’t download - Could not retrieve data form URL**.

I also checked the "See exactly what our scraper sees from your URL" option, and it seems the scraper only manages to read out the following line:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">`

The weird thing is that this isn't even the DOCTYPE I've got in the page's source.
I already tried changing the DOCTYPE to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

After I read some older posts saying this should fix the problem, but that doesn't work either – I keep on getting the same line from the scraper.
I'll be thankful for any tip or idea you guys have…

I posted the first part of the source, at least the part containing the meta tags. I'll add the whole code if necessary.
Thanks in advance,

David.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xml:lang="he" lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>לקסיקון הכיבוש: 67 שניות על... מאחז |בצלם</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="142675212478057"/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/sites/all/themes/btselem/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="בצלם" />
<meta property="og:title" content="מאחז | בצלם" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.btselem.org/hebrew/131606" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/sites/default/files2/css/css_1458508373fb743060ffb80b43b3d59c.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/sites/default/files2/css/css_ff9c22380c0853814b0563da89e16090.css" />
```

Comment: Using the [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I found that most of your pages work just fine, the ones that the debugger complains about are those with the format "/hebrew/NUMBER". And if you compare the html output of those with the other pages you'll notice that indeed there's something different, since they have different doctype definition. Try to find out why there's a change in the pages, then maybe you'll find out why this change is not very liked by facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! After changing the DOCTYPE, the problem persists - still getting that odd DOCTYPE from the scraper. So I guess it's not the DOCTYPE, or at least not the DOCTYPE alone. Any idea what else could cause this problem? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to put meta tags into your `<body>` tag.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.btselem.org%2Fhebrew%2F131606

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>UBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"&gt;</p>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

This isn't well formed HTML.  Fix up the HTML issues and then Facebook should be able to lint your page correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue just now when trying to have the Facebook Scraper ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) read an Object Graph file I created. When I had white space (spaces) before my "<meta property=..." the scraper showed that it was seeing my meta as part of the body tag and not the head tag which was the case. When i removed the white space before my meta tags, the scraper could correctly see the meta tags in the head and it worked well. For the sake of curiosity I replaced my previous 4 space width white space with tabs and the scraper was able to correctly see the content. Very strange. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the generated source of your document, there is a blank line that appears before your `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.

The 206 response code usually indicates that the requester has cancelled the transmission. It may be the blank line is confusing the Facebook parser and it's just giving up.

I haven't worked with Drupal much, but in other PHP based CMS systems, this usually occurs because there is whitespace between a closing `?>` tag and the `EOF` marker in a php file that is called before the header renders. [It seems to be agreed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236493/what-are-the-arguments-in-favor-of-php-closing-tags-for-php-only-files) that omitting these closing php tags wherever possible is a best practice.

Before you go through the process of editing all your PHP files, you could test this by copying the source for this page and saving it as a static html file on your sever without the whitespace. See if that will get parsed by the Facebook debugger. If it doesn't, then you've got another problem.