# How to show "open" and "close" PHP tags in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, tags

Netbeans shows corresponding braces like `{` and `}` with a different color. Is there a way in Netbeans to find the corresponding PHP close Tag (`?>`) to an existing PHP open Tag (`<?php` or `<?`)?

Comment: I hope your PHP file only contains 1 `<?php` and 1 `?>`

Comment: @Bondye It's fine to have lots of PHP tags? Inline PHP etc..

Comment: @Bondye View templates may legitimately have many `<?php ?>` pairs.

Comment: Not fine just able. Not readable and no good split languages.

Comment: Not all the opening <?php must have a ?> closing, instead is a good practice **not** to write ?> at the end of PHP code

Comment: @m4t10 - I've never heard that before. Can you point me to more info on why that is?

Comment: @David Grenier, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236493/what-are-the-arguments-in-favor-of-php-closing-tags-for-php-only-files

Comment: Omitting closingtags is a BAD habbit, despite popular culture. If you cannot manage avoiding outputting after the closingtag (when you don't want to), you shouldn't be a programmer.

Comment: @ErwinMoller <ironic>so that is the reason why Zend Framework, Symfony, Drupal... uses this practice</ironic>

Comment: @m4t1t0: correct. You have to think for yourself, not follow blindly (bad) practices. Tell me why you should ommit closingtags.

Comment: @ErwinMoller the same reason why I often do backups of my code and clean my databases and update my systems, to avoid problems and mistakes.

Comment: @m4t1t0: SO you don't have a real reason and resort to snappy remarks, correct?

Comment: All your comments are off topic. yawn. not using closing php tags is like not using semicolons `;` in javascript. You can do it if you know how and when to do it. Telling someone they shouldn't be a programmer for not using closing php tags is retarded. There are a lot of reasons for not using closing tags. One of them being personal preference.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos: I think you yawned too much when reading my message. I never wrote that somebody shouldn't be a programmer if they ommoit closingtags. I wrote that if they cannot manage to NOT output anything after the closingtag, they shouldn't be a programmer. Please stop putting words into my mouth, thanks. And if you don't care about the subject, why add noise to it? Matt and I are perfectly able to flame on our own. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Currently (in NetBeans 7.3 Beta), you cannot change or customize the Highlighting through the Tools > Options menu by adding a matching category for the tag. Best you can do is change the color of the syntax color for PHP Open/Close Tag (in screenshot 2)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's not perfect, but it helps to change the background color.